# How to get original number when 4% has been subtracted

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to reverse the effect of subtracting 4% from a large anmount of numbers.

One example: There was subtracted 4% from 100 making it 96. What kind of formula would make it 100 again?

**UPDATE:**

Above is just an example. For the vast majority of the numbers I only know that 4% was subtracted. Something like this 100 - ((100 / 100) x 4))

Is it possible to do something like we do with Danish VAT:

- Subtract 20% VAT: 100 x 0.80 = 80
- Add the 25% VAT back: 80 x 1.25 = 100

Comment: Divide by $0.96$...

Comment: you mean "Substract 20% VAT"?

Comment: Yes, my fault...

Comment: Spelling hint: it's `subtract`; the only `s` there is the initial one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"$-4$%" means, that you have to multiply with $\frac{96}{100}$. To get the origininal value, you just have to multiply with $\frac{100}{96}$

**Edit** (Related to your update)**:**
It's exactly the same:

- Subtract 20% VAT means, you have to multiply with 
  $$\frac{100-\boldsymbol{20}}{100}=\frac{80}{100} = 0.8$$
- to go back to the original value you have to multiply with
  $$\frac{100}{100-\boldsymbol{20}}=\frac{100}{80} = 1.25$$